# Module pattern that passes jQuery or different global

Tags: javascript, module-pattern

Is this pattern :

```
// Global module
var myModule = (function ( jQ, _ ) {

    function privateMethod1(){
        jQ(".container").html("test");
    }

    function privateMethod2(){
      console.log( _.min([10, 5, 100, 2, 1000]) );
    }

    return{
        publicMethod: function(){
            privateMethod1();                
        }            
    };

// Pull in jQuery and Underscore
}( jQuery, _ ));

myModule.publicMethod();
```

I don't understand what is the purpose of passing global, if it is anyway global ?

Is this more efficient to have jQuery or other global "closer" not so far away in prototype chain ?

And if someone wants to use

```
jQ
```

That refers to jQuery

Why just don't do

```
var jQ = jQuery
```

In scope he/she wants to use it.

Comment: did you actually see this in use somewhere?

Comment: @ben336 No I didn't only in the book. And sorry I didn't add the source:

http://addyosmani.com/resources/essentialjsdesignpatterns/book/#modulepatternjavascript

Comment: mmhmm, its explained within that link.  See my answer below, updated with the quote from that link.

Answer (score 0):

One reason to do this would be if you have multiple versions of jQuery on a page using jQuery [noconflict](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.noConflict/), you could isolate this code from having to know about that or worry about it.  You would just pass the correct version.  If you want to use the `$` shorthand, this could also be good to prevent conflict with other librarys such as Mootools that also use the `$` symbol.

In general though I agree with you that it doesn't seem especially useful.

### Update

That does in fact seem to be the reason for this particular useage.  From the [source you linked](http://addyosmani.com/resources/essentialjsdesignpatterns/book/#jquerypluginpatterns):

> Here, we’ve wrapped our plugin logic in an anonymous function. To ensure that our use of the $ sign as a shorthand creates no conflicts between jQuery and other JavaScript libraries, we simply pass it to this closure, which maps it to the dollar sign.

and also

> This variation of the pattern demonstrates how globals (e.g jQuery, Underscore) can be passed in as arguments to our module's anonymous function. This effectively allows us to import them and locally alias them as we wish.

So its used as a contrived example to show that you can alias globals if you prefer a shorter name.